# Using methods of react component in native dom element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I'm using React with Fluxxor to create a tree like visual component. For each node in the tree I want to provide basic functionality like deleting/editing the node or adding a new child. So every node has its own dropdown menu for these actions, the dropdowns are done with [MaterializeCss Framework](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html), and initially I created each of them inside the render method but then that cause a React error which I solved by rendering the a tag trigger inside the render function, and the ul that is used for the menu is created in the `componentDidMount` function using Jquery's append on the body element. The problem is that I want to map each of these actions to functions define in the React component, but it doesn't work out and it never gets called, how can I do this?

```
var ItemOferta = React.createClass({
    mixins: [FluxMixin],
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var id = "dd"+this.props.item.self.id;
        $("body").append(
            "<ul id='"+id+"' class='dropdown-content'>"+
            "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Agregar hijo</a></li>"+
            "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Editar</a></li>"+
            "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='"+this.eliminar+"'>"+
            "Eliminar</a></li></ul>");
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function(){
        var id = "#dd"+this.props.item.self.id;
        $(id).remove();
    },
    eliminar: function(e){
        console.log("En el metodo eliminar");
        this.getFlux().actions.eliminarNivel(this.props.item.self.id);
    },
    render: function(){
         ...
         <div className="acciones">
             <a href="#" className="accion dropdown-button" 
                data-activates={"dd"+this.props.item.self.id}>
                <i className="mdi-navigation-more-vert"></i>
             </a>
         </div>
        ...
        );
    }
});
```

I omitted some code of the render method, I only posted the code for the dropdown trigger, as you can see in the `onclick` attribute I try to bind the `this.eliminar` function, but when I check it with the Chrome tools all appears is this `function () { [native code] }`.

Comment: Can you please open source the tree viewer once complete please ?

Comment: Can you let me know if my answer helped?

Comment: @DeepakPrasanna It actually helped, thanks a lot, my initial idea was rendering the ul menu inside the render method, but that cause an invariant violation because the plugin that I'm using modifies the DOM when initializing the dropdown.

Comment: Ok @Peter I will post a link here to the code when I'm done, probably in the weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is against React's principle.
Changing the DOM elements will make React's DOM 
diffing absurd. You can fix your code like below. **But highly not recommended.**

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var id = "dd"+this.props.item.self.id;
    var ulMarkup = "<ul id='"+id+"' class='dropdown-content'>"+
                   "<li><a>Agregar hijo</a></li>"+
                   "<li><a>Editar</a></li>"+
                   "<li><a class='eliminar'>Eliminar</a></li></ul>"

    var ulElement = $(ulMarkup).appendTo('body');

    $(ulElement).find("a").click(function() { return false; });
    $(ulElement).find("a.eliminar").click(this.eliminar);
}
```

The correct approach of doing it the React way would be like below.

```
render: function(){
     ...
     <div className="acciones">
         <a href="#" className="accion dropdown-button" 
            data-activates={"dd"+this.props.item.self.id}>
            <i className="mdi-navigation-more-vert"></i>
         </a>
         <ul className='dropdown-content'>
           <li><a>Agregar hijo</a></li>
           <li><a>Editar</a></li>
           <li><a onClick={this.eliminar}>Eliminar</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
    ...
}
```